# Bing Maps API - mapArea: this parameter value is out of range

Tags: botframework, bing-maps, bing-api, azure-maps

I'm using the Bing Maps API to generate images from certain locations using the BotFramework-Location NuGet package. (Which code can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location))

Sometimes it works, but sometimes the images are not loaded due to an error in the Rest call (which is called by the BotFramework, not by me)

This is my code:

```
IGeoSpatialService geoService = new AzureMapsSpatialService(this.azureApiKey);
List < Location > concreteLocations = new List < Location > ();

foreach(String location in locations) {
 LocationSet locationSet = await geoService.GetLocationsByQueryAsync(location);
 concreteLocations.AddRange(locationSet ? .Locations);
}

// Filter out duplicates
var seenKeys = new HashSet < String > ();
var uniqueLocations = new List < Location > ();

foreach(Location location in concreteLocations) {
 if (seenKeys.Add(location.Address.AddressLine)) {
  uniqueLocations.Add(location);
 }
}

concreteLocations = new List < Location > (uniqueLocations.Take(5));

if (concreteLocations.Count == 0) {
 await context.PostAsync("No dealers found.");
 context.Done(true);
} else {
 var locationsCardReply = context.MakeMessage();
 locationsCardReply.Attachments = new LocationCardBuilder(this.bingApiKey, new LocationResourceManager()).CreateHeroCards(concreteLocations).Select(card => card.ToAttachment()).ToList();
 locationsCardReply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
 await context.PostAsync(locationsCardReply);
}
```

Which responds this:
[image: Location HeroCards returned by BotFramework-Location NuGet Package.]

The reason not all images are shown is because the Rest call to the Bing Maps API returns this:

> mapArea: This parameter value is out of range.

Here is one of the image uris that fail (I removed my key):

> https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Map/Road?form=BTCTRL&mapArea=49.5737,5.53792,49.57348,5.53744&mapSize=500,280&pp=49.5737,5.53744;1;1&dpi=1&logo=always&key=NOT_REAL_12758FDLKJLDKJO8769KLJDLKJF

Anyone know what I've been doing wrong?

Comment: Can you also provide the information you passed to get this working example that you showed? I'd like to investigate on the repo to see if there is something on that side. I think that for your 1st item it is using another method to generate the image, hence the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understood why you got that error. I tried to get this map and got the same result as yours, as you said:

> mapArea: This parameter value is out of range.

If you look at the sample url you provided, the `mapArea` is equal to `49.5737,5.53792,49.57348,5.53744`

So I just inverted the coordinates of the 2 points defining this area, putting the one with the smaller latitude value first, I got a reply:

[image: Image from maps]

***EDIT:***

As you commented, this call is made inside `BotBuilder-Location` code, not on yours. I had a look to it, this is the method to generate the map, called inside `LocationCardBuilder` class that you are instantiating:

```
public string GetLocationMapImageUrl(Location location, int? index = null)
{
    if (location == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(location));
    }

    var point = location.Point;
    if (point == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(point));
    }

    if (location.BoundaryBox != null && location.BoundaryBox.Count >= 4)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            ImageUrlByBBox,
            location.BoundaryBox[0],
            location.BoundaryBox[1],
            location.BoundaryBox[2],
            location.BoundaryBox[3],
            point.Coordinates[0],
            point.Coordinates[1], 
            index, 
            this.apiKey);
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
            ImageUrlByPoint, 
            point.Coordinates[0], 
            point.Coordinates[1], 
            index, 
            apiKey);
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is no restriction on the format of the BoundaryBox item. But if you look at the documentation about location data [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701725.aspx?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365):

> BoundingBox: A geographic area that contains the location. A bounding box contains **SouthLatitude, WestLongitude, NorthLatitude, and EastLongitude** values in units of degrees.

As you may know, in code, SouthLatitude is smaller that NorthLatitude (as it expressed with positive and negative values in code depending on the location compared to Ecuador: 43N is 43, 43S is -43). So the problem seems to be here.

I made a quick test to see if I got the error base on the call you are doing before (to `GetLocationsByQueryAsync`), I wasn't able to reproduce this case. Can you share the query you did that linked to this problem?

Comment: that's a step in the right direction. Unfortunately, I didn't generate the image URL. It was provided by the Bing Maps API, which would mean it's out of my control. Also, the image should be generated in a way that the blue marker is centered, which means the Bing Maps API did some wrong calculations or something. Thanks anyway!

Comment: as the code is open-sourced, feel free to raise an issue on github and even provide a solution if you can

Comment: I edited my answer to give more details. I looked at the code on the repo, it seems ok. Can you share the `locations` content that you are querying?

Comment: The queries are the addresses on the bottom of the cards.